# Logstash and filebeat set event.dataset value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I've a configuration in which filebeat fetches logs from some files (using a custom format) and sends those logs to a logstash instance.

In logstash I apply a gork filter in order to split some of the fields and then I send the output to my elasticsearch instance.

The pipeline works fine and it is correctly loaded on elasticsearch, but no event data is present (such as `event.dataset` or `event.module`). So I'm looking for the piece of code for adding such information to my events.

Here my filebeat configuration:

```yaml
filebeat.config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: false

filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    paths:
      - /var/log/*/info.log
      - /var/log/*/warning.log
      - /var/log/*/error.log



output.logstash:
  hosts: '${ELK_HOST:logstash}:5044'
```

Here my logstash pipeline:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "MY PATTERN"}
    }
  mutate {
    add_field => { "logLevelLower" => "%{logLevel}" }
  }
  mutate {
    lowercase => [ "logLevelLower" ]
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    user => "USER"
    password => "PASSWORD"
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{logLevelLower}-%{[@metadata][version]}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this easily with a `mutate/add_field` filter:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => {
        "[ecs][version]" => "1.5.0"
        "[event][kind]" => "event"
        "[event][category]" => "host"
        "[event][type]" => ["info"]
        "[event][dataset]" => "module.dataset"
    }
  }
}
```

The Elastic Common Schema documentation explains how to pick values for [`kind`, `category` and `type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-category-field-values-reference.html).